# Custom prices for customer

Tags: magento-1.9, price

I want to add custom prices for certain customers (individual customer not customer groups), is there a way in Magento that i can do this or will i need an extension for this? As i have found quite a few but wondered if there was an easy way of doing it myself first?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Note :: Here i have taken your customer as in assign some group

You can do this with simply add price with customer group wise for each products from magento admin

```
Go to product >> price tab
```

you can see Group Price option select your group in your case And

add price for **wholesale group** then

And add your other price for **general users**.

hope this will clear for you.

let me know if i could help you more in this.

Comment: Nah i mean individual customers, thanks for your reply though

Comment: ah ok. you have edited your question.you may use this extension http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/prices-per-customer-hide-product-prices.html
. i am not associated with above link at any point. its just for your help.